# System names of returned columns

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

I'm looking for a way to obtain system names of columns returned by an arbitrary sql query using Sql Server 2019. Here are a few sample queries and desired results:

```
company: id, name
employee: id, name, companyId

select * from company

| tableName | columnName |
  company     id
  company     name

select id as whatever from company

| tableName | columnName |
  company     id

select e.id, e.name, c.name from employee e join company c on e.companyId = c.id

| tableName | columnName |
  employee    id
  employee    name
  company     name
```

I'm not in control of the input queries, they are provided by end users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set DMF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) returns column meta-data for the specified query, including additional information about the source column when `@include_browse_information = 1` (the third parameter) is specified:

```
SELECT 
      source_schema AS tableSchema
    , source_table AS tableName
    , source_column AS columnName
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'select * from company;',NULL,1);
```

Comment: great, it even returns data type of the columns. Thank you!